# css 3dscale(x,y,z) not working as intended

Tags: css, 3d, position, scale, transition

I am trying to do the tooltip effect as the following link shows: http://tympanus.net/Development/TooltipStylesInspiration/line.html

Please refer to my source code: http://jsfiddle.net/39a3ojwc/

I have two questions :

FIRST - I can not figure out why the `transform: scale3d` is not working here when you hover on that pink bar. Am I missing anything in the css?

SECOND - Why is my white bar underneath the green arrow? I set both element `position: absolute` but `bottom: 200%` and `bottom: 100%` respectively. Shouldn't they sit above the pink bar the amount of distance of their parent's height (a.wrapper  AKA the pink bar)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: `transform: scale3d is not working`

Well, this is working. In fact  it is working so fast that you can't even notice. Here you need to apply the transition speed. `transition:1s`

Second: You need not to set the `bottom:100%`

```
.content::after{
content: "";
width: 0; 
height: 0;
border-top: 10px solid green;
border-left:10px solid transparent;
border-right:10px solid transparent;    
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;    
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
bottom: -10px; /*----adjusted it.----*/
transform: translateX(-50%);

}
```

Hope this help you. Your [updated Code](https://jsfiddle.net/5tb98mky/), and [this is](https://jsfiddle.net/uk8qmd37/1/) almost what you want. Do come back if still face any issue.!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I do encounter another issue though. Please check out this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/uk8qmd37/3/). I wonder if we need to have some sort of screen or just setting the z-index to have a layer order in order to hide the element `.inner`. Any thought is greatly appreciated.